# Bullet under the list item

Tags: html, css

As you can see in the picture there is a bullet infront of the list item "Fashion", this is shown only on the hover state. My goal is to place the bullet under the list item.

[image]

This is my CSS for now:

```
.top-menu-left ul li a:hover:before
{
  content: "\2022";
  color: inherit;
  padding-right: 4px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
```

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: Myself I believe adding a bullet image or just an "o" inside the <li> and just placing it below the text would be a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I made a few changes to your code which should solve your problem:

- Increasing the distance of the bullet from the top
- Centering it via `left: 50%` and `translateX(-50%)`
- Setting the bullet to be position absolute and it's parent `li` to position relative, or else your link would shift slightly to the right whenever you would hover over it (and also centering it would be slightly more difficult)

You can look at the snippet below to see the final result:

```css
.top-menu-left ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.top-menu-left ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.top-menu-left ul li + li {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.top-menu-left ul li a:hover:before {
  content: "\2022";
  position: absolute;
  top: 1em;
  left: 50%;
  translate: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-menu-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a>FASHION</a></li>
    <li><a>TRAVEL</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

## Edit:

Since you are trying to place the bullet *after* the list item, you should instead be using the `after` pseudo-element (thanks to @ErickPetrucelli).

If you want, you can still position it via `right` (instead of `left`) and `translateX`, or if you don't want to do that, you could instead go for the following approach:

```
.top-menu-left ul li a:hover:after {
  [...]
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

There is just one minor difference between both techniques: while positioning it via `left: 0` or `right: 0` and `translateX(-50%)` will only take up the required space for the bullet (left picture), centering it via `display: block` and `text-align: center` stretches the area to a full block (right picture).

[image: Centering technique - difference in width]

---

## Conclusion:

Considering you are probably only going to display the aforementioned bullet, it doesn't matter which method you use.
But lets say you wanted to display some text bellow the link instead, then the `display: block` method is probably going to serve you better because it allows the text to wrap nicely (right picture) where as with the former method, the text wouldn't be centered and would overflow (left picture).

[image: Centering technique - difference in wrapping]

Comment: It does not makes sense to reposition a `:before` generated element to work like an `:after`, just use the right pseudoelement.

Comment: @Erick Petrucelli but since you have to set it to `position: absolute` anyways (or else your content below would shift when hovering), it doesn't matter.

Comment: @TobiasMeister, the `position: absolute` is really inevitable, but the repositioning with `left` and `translate` is.

Comment: @ErickPetrucelli I can follow you on the `:after` part, but don't see the need to change the way for centering the bullet. Anyhows, I have edited my answer to reflect on this conversation.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest just generate the bullet `:after` the anchor contents (and not `:before`), letting `display: block` and `text-align: center` solve the problem for you. I also removed `ul li` to make more clear and to better demonstrate that the solution is with the `a` itself.

```css
.top-menu-left {
  display: flex;
}
.top-menu-left a {
  color: #111;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-menu-left a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.top-menu-left a:hover:after {
  content: '\2022';
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-menu-left">
  <a href="#fashion">Fashion</a>
  <a href="#travel">Travel</a>
</nav>
```

Of couse, if you really like to structure your HTML with the list item:

```css
.top-menu-left ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.top-menu-left a {
  display: block;
  color: #111;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-menu-left a:hover {
  color: #666;
}
.top-menu-left a:hover:after {
  content: '\2022';
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: -4px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="top-menu-left">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#fashion">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#travel">Travel</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```